# Div not expanding with content inside

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically, in the #main-content div, I would like it to expand, so the de facto content of that div fits inside and is not overlapping, like you see in the codepen.

I don't know how to implement the clearfix solution or the overflow:hidden solution. I've tried but failed.

I don't know why, but the p tag is not overlapping, but the JavaScript/jQuery progress bars are. :/

Codepen: http://codepen.io/DocRow10/pen/hjIkq

**Snippet:**

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
}

#nav-bar {
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
 background-color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
 border-bottom-style: solid;
 border-bottom-color: rgb(238, 0, 0);
 border-bottom-width: 7.5px;
 padding-top: 14px
  
}

#logo {
 position: relative;
 bottom: 5px;
 font-size: 30px;
 padding-left: 8px;
 float: left;
 font-family: bebas;
}

#word-1 {
 color: rgb(0, 154, 205);
}

#word-2 {
 color: rgb(255, 250, 250);
}

ul#main-links {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding-right: 50px;
 float: right;
 height: 100%;
 border-bottom: 7.5px solid transparent;
 display: block;
font-size: 0;
}

ul#main-links li {
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
 border-bottom-style: solid;
 border-bottom-width: 7.5px;
border-bottom-color: rgb(238, 0, 0);
 color: white;
 font-family: arcon;
 font-size: 18px;
 height: 100%;
 width: 90px;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 2;
}

a:link {
 text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
}

a:active {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
}

a#logo-link {
 text-decoration: none;
 
}

a#logo-link:visited {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: inherit;
}

a#logo-link:active {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: inherit;
}

ul#main-links > a > li > span.word-position {
 position: relative;
 top: 5px;
}

#main-content {
 background-color: rgb(131, 111, 255);
 width: 100%;
 height: 80%;
 
}

#background {
 
  
}

h1#page-header {
 margin: 0;
 font-family: code;
 font-size: 45px;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 5px 0px;
}

/* ABOUT */

#pic-container {
 width: 100%;
 height: 180px;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 10px;
}

#relative {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 right: 97.5px;
}

#photo-frame {
 background-color: royalblue;
 position: absolute;
 width: 0px;
 height: 0px;
 border-radius: 100px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: beige;
 border-width: 0px;
 top: 90px;
 left: 90px;
}

#photo-frame > #picture {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-image: url('Ed.png');
 border-radius: 100px;
}

hr {
 position: relative;
 top: 97.5px;
 margin: 0;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: black;
 overflow: hidden;
 height 2px;
 background-color: black;
}

.hidari {
 float: left;
}

.migi {
 float: right;
}

.clear {
 width: 100%; clear: both; height: 0px; line-height:0px;
}

#intro {
 width: 70%;
 font-family: lato;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 text-align: justify;
 font-size: 17px;
 line-height: 150%;
}

#expertise {
 width: 80%;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 text-align: center;
}

#expertise h1 {
 font-family: Arial;
 font-size: 25px;
}

#expertise h2 {
 font-family: sinkinsans;
 font-size: 18px;
 margin-top: 5px;
}

#skills {
 width: 50%;
 height: 100px;
}

.skill {
 
}

/*-----SKILLS BAR-----*/

.bar {
 width: 300px;
 height: 35px;
 border: 2px solid black;
 border-radius: 10px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
   
.nil {
 background-image: url('footer_lodyas.png'); /* Background pattern from subtlepatterns.com */
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
     
 float: right;
 overflow: hidden;
}
   
ability {
 width: 77%;
 height: 100%;
 background: red; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, red , lime); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
 background: -o-linear-gradient(right, red, lime); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, red, lime); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
 background: linear-gradient(to right, red , lime); /* Standard syntax */
 border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
 border-top-right-radius: 20px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 7.5px;
 border-top-left-radius: 7.5px; 
    /*  border-radius: 7.5px; */
}

/*--------------------*/
#experience {
 width: 50%;
 height: 100px;
}


/*---------------------------------------------------------------*/

/* CONTACT */

#contact-info {
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 width: 80%;
 height: 80%;
}

#contact-info td {
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 width: 50%;
}

#contact-info td > p {
 text-align: justify;
 font-family: lato;
 width: 80%;
 
}

.spacer {
 padding: 10px 0px;
}

#message-div {
 height: 150px;
}

input[type="text"] {
 width: 100%;
 height: 27px;
 padding-left: 5px;
 font-family: Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;
 font-size: 15px;
}

input[type="text"]:hover, #recipient-message:hover {
 border-width: 1.5px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: rgb(152, 245, 255);
}

input[type="button"] {
 float: right;
 margin-top: 7.5px;
 background-color: rgb(72, 118, 215);
 border-color: rgb(72, 118, 215);
 border-radius: 5px;
 font-size: 15px;
 color: rgb(230, 230, 255);
 font-family: Tahoma;
}

label {
 font-family: lato;
 font-size: 18px;
}

#recipient-message {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 resize: none;
 font-family: Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;
 font-size: 12.5px;
}

.form-confirmation {
 width: 80%;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 2.5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.invalid-field {
 box-shadow: 0 0 23px red;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 23px red;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 23px red;
}

#success {
 background-color: rgb(0, 210, 0);
 color: rgb(245, 255, 250);
 
}

#failure {
 background-color: rgb(255, 48, 48);
 color: rgb(137, 0, 0);
}

.form-confirmation > p {
  text-align: center;
 font-family: codee;
 font-size: 18px;
}

#footer {
 width: 100%;
 height: 10%;
 background-color: black;
}

#footer > p#footer-text {
 margin: 0;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: arial;
 color: rgb(169, 169, 169);
 padding-top: 20px;
 width: 100%;
}

@font-face {
 font-family: arcon;
 src: url(Arcon-Regular.otf);
}

@font-face {
 font-family: bebas;
 src: url(BEBAS___.ttf);
}

@font-face {
 font-family: bubblegum;
 src: url(BubblegumSans-Regular.otf);
}

@font-face {
 font-family: code;
 src: url(Days.otf);
}

@font-face {
 font-family: lato;
 src: url(Lato-Regular.ttf);
}

@font-face {
 font-family: codee;
 src: url(CODE_Bold.otf);
}

@font-face {
 font-family: sinkinsans;
 src: url(SinkinSans-400Regular.otf);
}

.clear {
 clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
 <div id="nav-bar">
  <div id="logo"><a id="logo-link" href="index.html"><span id="word-1">Potential </span><span id="word-2">Beginning</span></a></div>
  <ul id="main-links">
   <a href="about.html"><li><span class="word-position">About</span></li></a>
   <a href="work.html"><li><span class="word-position">Work</span></li></a>
   <a class href="contact.php"><li><span class="word-position">Contact</span></li></a>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div id="main-content">
  <div id="pic-container">
   <div id="relative">
    <div id="photo-frame">
     <div id="picture"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <hr class="hidari" />
   
   
   <hr class="migi" />
  </div>
  
  <h1 id="page-header">About Me</h1>
  <p id="intro">Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content!  </p>
  <div id="expertise">
   <div id="skills" class="hidari">
    <h1>Skills</h1>
    <div class="skill">
     <h2>HTML/CSS</h2>
     <div class="bar migi">
      <div class="nil">
       <div class="ability">
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="skill">
     <h2>JavaScript/jQuery</h2>
     <div class="bar migi">
      <div class="nil">
       <div class="ability">
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="skill">
     <h2>JavaScript/jQuery</h2>
     <div class="bar migi">
      <div class="nil">
       <div class="ability">
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="skill">
     <h2>JavaScript/jQuery</h2>
     <div class="bar migi">
      <div class="nil">
       <div class="ability">
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="skill">
     <h2>JavaScript/jQuery</h2>
     <div class="bar migi">
      <div class="nil">
       <div class="ability">
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    
   </div>
   <div id="experience" class="migi">
    <h1>Experience</h1>
    
   </div>
   <span class="clear"></span>
  </div>
 </div>
 <span class="clear"></span>
 <div id="footer">
  
  <p id="footer-text">
   &#169; 2016. All rights reserved.
  </p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Dont understand ur question. please be specific and clear enough

Comment: can you please give better explanation??

Comment: I would recommend changing the `clear` class from a span to a div or adding a `display:block;` to the clear class. Span does not have a display property by default, which is needed to clear the floats correctly.

Comment: Adding height to the expertise div also helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

#nav-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: rgb(238, 0, 0);
  border-bottom-width: 7.5px;
  padding-top: 14px
      
}

#logo {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding-left: 8px;
    float: left;
    font-family: bebas;
}

#word-1 {
    color: rgb(0, 154, 205);
}

#word-2 {
    color: rgb(255, 250, 250);
}

ul#main-links {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-right: 50px;
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
  border-bottom: 7.5px solid transparent;
  display: block;
font-size: 0;
}

ul#main-links li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 7.5px;
border-bottom-color: rgb(238, 0, 0);
  color: white;
  font-family: arcon;
  font-size: 18px;
  height: 100%;
    width: 90px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

a#logo-link {
    text-decoration: none;
    
}

a#logo-link:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}

a#logo-link:active {
  text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}

ul#main-links > a > li > span.word-position {
  position: relative;
    top: 5px;
}

#main-content {
    background-color: rgb(131, 111, 255);
    width: 100%;
    
    
}

#background {
    
   
}

h1#page-header {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: code;
    font-size: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0px;
}

/* ABOUT */

#pic-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 180px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

#relative {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    right: 97.5px;
}

#photo-frame {
    background-color: royalblue;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: beige;
    border-width: 0px;
    top: 90px;
    left: 90px;
}

#photo-frame > #picture {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('Ed.png');
    border-radius: 100px;
}

hr {
    position: relative;
    top: 97.5px;
    margin: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
    height 2px;
    background-color: black;
}

.hidari {
    float: left;
}

.migi {
    float: right;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}

#intro {
    width: 70%;
    font-family: lato;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 150%;
}

#expertise {
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#expertise h1 {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 25px;
}

#expertise h2 {
    font-family: sinkinsans;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

#skills {
    width: 50%;
    overflow: auto;
    
}

.skill {
    
}

/*-----SKILLS BAR-----*/

.bar {
    width: 300px;
    height: 35px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
        
.nil {
    background-image: url('footer_lodyas.png'); /* Background pattern from subtlepatterns.com */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
           
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
}
        
.ability {
    width: 77%;
    height: 100%;
    background: red; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, red , lime); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(right, red, lime); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, red, lime); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, red , lime); /* Standard syntax */
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 7.5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 7.5px; 
         /*  border-radius: 7.5px; */
}

/*--------------------*/
#experience {
    width: 50%;
    
}


/*---------------------------------------------------------------*/

/* CONTACT */

#contact-info {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
}

#contact-info td {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 50%;
}

#contact-info td > p {
    text-align: justify;
    font-family: lato;
    width: 80%;
    
}

.spacer {
    padding: 10px 0px;
}

#message-div {
    height: 150px;
}

input[type="text"] {
    width: 100%;
    height: 27px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    font-family: Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
}

input[type="text"]:hover, #recipient-message:hover {
    border-width: 1.5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgb(152, 245, 255);
}

input[type="button"] {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 7.5px;
    background-color: rgb(72, 118, 215);
    border-color: rgb(72, 118, 215);
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: rgb(230, 230, 255);
    font-family: Tahoma;
}

label {
    font-family: lato;
    font-size: 18px;
}

#recipient-message {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    resize: none;
    font-family: Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12.5px;
}

.form-confirmation {
    width: 80%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2.5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.invalid-field {
    box-shadow: 0 0 23px red;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 23px red;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 23px red;
}

#success {
    background-color: rgb(0, 210, 0);
    color: rgb(245, 255, 250);
    
}

#failure {
    background-color: rgb(255, 48, 48);
    color: rgb(137, 0, 0);
}

.form-confirmation > p {
   text-align: center;
    font-family: codee;
    font-size: 18px;
}

#footer {
    width: 100%;
    
    background-color: black;
}

#footer > p#footer-text {
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: arial;
    color: rgb(169, 169, 169);
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: arcon;
  src: url(Arcon-Regular.otf);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: bebas;
  src: url(BEBAS___.ttf);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: bubblegum;
  src: url(BubblegumSans-Regular.otf);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: code;
  src: url(Days.otf);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: lato;
  src: url(Lato-Regular.ttf);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: codee;
  src: url(CODE_Bold.otf);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: sinkinsans;
    src: url(SinkinSans-400Regular.otf);
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>About | Potential Beginning</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/
libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="nav-bar">
                <div id="logo"><a id="logo-link" href="index.html"><span id="word-1">Potential </span><span id="word-2">Beginning</span></a></div>
                <ul id="main-links">
                    <a href="about.html"><li><span class="word-position">About</span></li></a>
                    <a href="work.html"><li><span class="word-position">Work</span></li></a>
                    <a class href="contact.php"><li><span class="word-position">Contact</span></li></a>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="main-content">
                <div id="pic-container">
                    <div id="relative">
                        <div id="photo-frame">
                            <div id="picture"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr class="hidari" />
                    
                    
                    <hr class="migi" />
                </div>
                
                <h1 id="page-header">About Me</h1>
                <p id="intro">Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content! Dummy Content!</p>

                <div id="expertise">
                    <div id="skills" class="hidari">
                        <h1>Skills</h1>
                        <div class="skill">
                            <h2>HTML/CSS</h2>
                            <div class="bar migi">
                                <div class="nil">
                                    <div class="ability">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <div class="skill">
                            <h2>JavaScript/jQuery</h2>
                            <div class="bar migi">
                                <div class="nil">
                                    <div class="ability">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <div class="skill">
                            <h2>JavaScript/jQuery</h2>
                            <div class="bar migi">
                                <div class="nil">
                                    <div class="ability">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <div class="skill">
                            <h2>JavaScript/jQuery</h2>
                            <div class="bar migi">
                                <div class="nil">
                                    <div class="ability">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <div class="skill">
                            <h2>JavaScript/jQuery</h2>
                            <div class="bar migi">
                                <div class="nil">
                                    <div class="ability">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="experience" class="migi">
                        <h1>Experience</h1>
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div id="footer">
                
                <p id="footer-text">
                    &#169; 2016. All rights reserved.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#main-links li").on('mouseenter', function() {

                    $(this).animate({borderBottomColor: "rgb(0, 154, 205)"},"200");
                });
                
               $("#main-links li").on('mouseleave', function() {

                    $(this).animate({borderBottomColor: "rgb(238, 0, 0)"},"200");
                });
                
                $("#picture").fadeOut();
                
                $("hr").delay(800).animate(
                    {
                        width: "50%"
                    }, 3200
                );
                
             
                
                $("#photo-frame").delay(4000).animate(
                    {
                        width: "180px",
                        height: "180px",
                        top: "-=90px",
                        left: "-=90px",
                        borderLeftWidth: "7.5px",
                        borderTopWidth: "7.5px",
                        borderRightWidth: "7.5px",
                        borderBottomWidth: "7.5px"
                    }, "slow", function() {
                       $("hr").animate(
                            {
                                width: "0%"
                            }, 2700
                         );
                        $("#picture").fadeIn(2000);
                    });
                

                
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Adding `overflow:auto` should do the trick, this will prevent the content from overlapping due to floats.

CSS:

```
#expertise
{
  overflow:auto;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Kritika/u9egtedy/)

**P.S**: since you have added `height:100px;` to `#skills` in css , you get scroll bar in that section.

**[DEMO-2](https://jsfiddle.net/u9egtedy/1/)** - This demo shows without scrollbar, I have removed the `height` for `#skills div` or you can set the `height` to `auto`.

See the updated code below:
i)Change the `span` to `div` for `clear class`
ii)remove the height for `#skills` div
iii)remove height of `#main-content` and `#footer` , this will make the content flow as and when the content fills,height is not required. [And main-content u have mentioned as 80% and footer as 20% which already equals to 100% excluding the header,always try to split the height equal if required.]
iv) I have added `clear div` after each skill to make each skill flow below each other, else the alignment goes wrong.
v) and u forgot to add '`.`' in front of `.ability` class in the css

Comment: So, if take away the height, the scroll bar will go away and the #main-content div will stretch to fit the content inside the elements.

Comment: I've just tested it, works like you say. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Chosen1: yes if u take away the height, the div will stretch to fit the content. (your welcome, happy to help.)

Comment: For some reason, I managed to emulate it on the fiddle, but for some reason, couldn't do it on my machine. Sorry to be a pain, but could you do another fiddle where the #main-content stretches without the scroll bar? I'm sorry to be a nuissance, but this is kind of important to me.

Comment: @Chosen1: Please see the updated changes. Let me know if u have any other doubts. The height has been removed for #skills.

Comment: Okay, I'm *really* sorry to keep pestering you on this this. I've literally copied and pasted that code on to my file and the same problem arises. Again, like before, I see the change on fiddle but not on my computer. This has really thrown me.

I've updated my codepen. The html area is a direct copy of my file (which is why it has link rel, jQuery etc.) and the css is a direct copy of my css file. If you have any spare time, do you think you could take that code and run it on your PC (not fiddle codepen etc.), to see if you can emulate the problem I am having?

Comment: Nonetheless, I honestly appreciate the input. This problem is stressing me out :/

Comment: @Chosen1: can u check now

Comment: You're an absolute legend, mate. Works perfectly. Thank you *so* much for your help!!! :)

Comment: Pbk1303 Hey man, long time no speak, I'm actually having the same king of problem, but I can't seem to get passed it, even implementing the solution for this problem. I was wondering if you could help me out with it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35115078/table-content-overlapping-div-and-not-expanding

Comment: @Chosen1: i am not able to replicate the issue , ur contact form with the css in the codepen seems to be working fine , even when i re-size the window.

Comment: Not a problem. Solved the issue anyway. Got the height values for the #main-content and set a min-height and min-width for them. Not the pretties way of doing it, but it works. I've deleted the question now, so you don't have to worry about it.

Thanks anyway. :)